# How can I make a static homepage while still using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

From my understanding, React.js isn't SEO friendly. I want to make my homepage static and not have React involved with rendering it so that I can optimize it to be as SEO friendly as possible. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't an advice forum; You need to do your own research. Please update your answer with more details about what you've looked at, what approaches you want to take, where you got your research from, etc.

Comment: *React.js isn't SEO friendly* that is a rather opinionated comment;  Just because React.js can produce code that isn't SEO friendly doesn't mean every piece of code is that way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [server side rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html), which leverages the React `renderToString` method, requires a dynamic web server.  [Here's a tutorial.](https://medium.com/@benlu/ssr-with-create-react-app-v2-1b8b520681d9)

> **renderToString()**
>
> Render a React element to its initial HTML. This should only be used
>   on the server. React will return an HTML string. You can use this
>   method to generate HTML on the server and send the markup down on the
>   initial request for faster page loads and to allow search engines to
>   crawl your pages for SEO purposes.
>
> If you call ReactDOM.render() on a node that already has this
>   server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
>   handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
>   experience.

Comment: Please update your answer with more detail than an off-site link. If that article ever disappears then your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Disagree.  The tutorial is a reference.  The answer to the question is server side rendering.

Comment: @Doug You can provide links, but those shouldn't be the only part of your answer. SO discourages this because it's fragile; The answer becomes useless if the link disappears. I've had to close many questions because of "dead answers". Please, take a moment to supplement the link with some context.